# Trying to replace contents of a Div, with no luck

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

Ive tried to use the Dom model with no bloody luck, getElementByID just doesnt work for me.

I loathe to resort to a regex but not sure what else to do.

The idea is to replace a `<div id="content_div"> all sorts </div>` with a new `<div id="content_div"> NEW ALL SORTS HERE </div>` and keep anything that was before or after it in the string.

The string is a partial HTML string and more specifically out of the wordpress Posts DB.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: I tagged this question PHP but probably should of mentioned Im looking for a PHP solution only.**

**Update: Code Example**

```
$content = ($wpdb->get_var( "SELECT `post_content` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = {$article[post_id]}" ));

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true; 
$doc->loadHTMLFile($content);   
$element = $doc->getElementById('div_to_edit');
```

So Ive tried a whole lot of code and this is what Ive got so far, probably not right but Ive been hacking at it for a little while now.

Comment: You need a proper DTD or XSD linked to the document in order to use `getElementById` - does your master document have a Doctype?

Additionally how are you currently creating and trying to replace the element?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'getElementByID just doesnt work for me.' ? it should do. or you can use a javascript library like prototype or jquery for easier accessing of the DOM.

Comment: document.getElementById do u have typo with getElementById

Comment: I need a php solution, not Java. the content is a snippet of HTML but I tried adding a doctype etc but still nada.

Comment: Are you using setIDAttribute() to set the ID attribute prior to calling getElementId?

Comment: the id attribute is already set in the content

Comment: Have you tried setting the validateOnParse-field to true on the document? 
$doc->validateOnParse = true;

This should be done before calling getElementById()

Comment: Yeah tried that as well, still couldnt get it working, just an empty object when I try

Comment: @daniel: why dont you post the code youve got so far. then we can correct you - there are a lot of things that could be going wrong and it will be easier for us to help if we know what youre actually doing.

Comment: Even if there are attributes named "ID" in the content, unless you're using a DTD that specifies what the ID attribute is, you must specify it with setIdAttribute(). You're not specifying the value, you're specifying the name.

Comment: javascript functions are case sensitive =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i assume `$content` is a snippet? then this may be all you need:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true; 
$doc->loadHTMLFile('<html><body>' . $content . '</body></html>');   
$element = $doc->getElementById('div_to_edit');
```

Comment: it is a snippet, so in your example how would I be able to to replace the div 'div_to_edit' with another div altogether and then save the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You're right: `getElementByID` doesn't work.

Try `getElementById()` instead. Javascript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

remember that you must have a valid webpage and that means full HTML tree:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(div){
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = 'my new text';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

--- your body ---

<div id="DIV_ID">old text</div>

<input type="button" onclick="chageText('DIV_ID');" value="Click me" />

</body>
</html>
```

remember that you have to call getElementById with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // as from HTML5 you can use only <script>
    document.getElementById("DIV_ID").innerHTML = 'my new text';
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('content_div');
myDiv.innerHTML = "NEW ALL SORTS HERE";
```

Comment: I think he is using php's DOMDocument ont he server side... not javascript.

Comment: Im looking for a PHP answer, I tagged it PHP but I probably should of mentioned that as well sorry.